# What does HTTP traffic that doesn't show "GET/POST/PUT/etc." signify? (Wireshark)

Tags: http, wireshark

I was analyzing a PCAP file when I saw that some traffic had been identified as HTTP by Wireshark - however, there was a lot of traffic that was simply labeled "TCP" and not HTTP, albeit being to/from port 80. Looking into these, I couldn't figure out what exactly was going on. Is this just traffic over port 80 that involves some kind of data being sent/received? In the packets Wireshark labeled as HTTP (and not TCP), there was an HTTP section in the packet details - this was not true for those marked TCP.

Please view the screenshots below:

- *Marked as just "TCP" traffic. It still says "HTTP" as you can see where I circled. This confused me:* [image: image 1]
- *Regular HTTP GET - Wireshark labeled it as HTTP and it has its own section:* [image: image 2]

Comment: Hint: look at the source and destination ports... The 2nd one is requrest, the 1st one is reply. Why Wireshark doesn't "understand" the reply as HTTP, I have no idea.

Comment: Ah! I see. So someone is answering that GET request with the data the person wanted. Is there a reason why the HTTP content is being put into the TCP section of the packet in the first example (and not an HTTP section)? Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response is split up among several, perhaps many, TCP segments.  By default, Wireshark will attempt to reassemble the TCP stream into the full HTTP response, but it only shows that HTTP response in the fully reassembled frame, not in the first TCP segment.

If all TCP segments were captured, and if you expand the TCP tree in the protocol details pane, you should see a tree item such as `[Reassembled PDU in frame: XXXXX]`.  The frame indicated is where Wireshark will show the HTTP response.

Note that this behavior can be modified.  If you prefer to see the very first TCP segment marked as the start of the HTTP response, you can disable TCP reassembly via *"Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> TCP -> Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams:deselect -> OK"*.